# Commutation relation of the second quantisation of an operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, commutator, second-quantization

Let $h$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathfrak{h}$ and $H_N:=\sum_{i=1}^N h_i$ defined on $H(\mathfrak{h})^{\otimes N}\subset \mathfrak{h}^{\otimes N}$. Let $\overline{\text{d}\Gamma(h)}$ be the second quantisation of $h$, $f\in D(h), \Psi\in D(H)\cap D(\mathcal{N^\alpha})$ for $\alpha\geq 1/2$.
How can I see that then for the annihilation operator $a(f)$ and the creation operator $a^\dagger(f)$ it holds the following commutation relations:
\begin{align}
[\overline{\text{d}\Gamma(h)}, a(f)] &= -a(hf)\\
[\overline{\text{d}\Gamma(h)}, a^\dagger(f)] &= a^\dagger(hf)\\
\end{align}
as bounded operators?

Answer (score 1):

I think that, in more conventional notation, you are saying that if
$$
H= a^\dagger_i h_{ij}a_j 
$$
with $h_{ij}$ a self-adjoint matrix representing a first quantized Hamiltonian and  $a$, $a^\dagger$ Fermi or Bosonic creators and annihilators,  then
$$
[H,a^\dagger_k]= -a^\dagger_i h_{ik}, \quad [H,a_k]=  h_{ki}a_i
$$
Both these follow from
$$
[AB,C]= A[B,C]+ [A,C]B
$$
in the Bose case  or
$$
[AB,C]= A\{B,C\} - \{A,C\}B
$$
in the Fermi case. Of course if you are worried about the functional analysis aspects or in what operator topology we have  convergence then more is needed.